# How to user "and" condition in cakephp model?

Tags: cakephp, model

I am using this to validate a form field

$valid = $this->isUnique(array($fieldName1 => $data, $fieldName2 => 'Y'));

executing this the query is coming like this:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `users` AS `User` WHERE ((`User`.`emailid` = ('paramita@navsoft.in')) OR (`User`.`isdeleted` = 'Y'))

I just need to change that "OR" to "AND".

Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The [API documentation](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelisUnique) is always a good read:

> **`Model::isUnique`**
>
> "Returns `false` if *any* fields passed match *any* (by default, **all if `$or = false`**) of their matching values."
>
> *Parameters:*
>
> `array $fields` *required*
> Field/value pairs to search (if no values specified, they are pulled from `$this->data`)
>
> **`boolean $or`** *optional, `true`*
> **If `false`, all fields specified must match in order for a `false` return value**
>
> *Return:*
> `boolean` `False` if any records matching any fields are found

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you are assigning your validation to a variable. Otherwise all your validation should be done inside your model in the `validate` array.

Take a look at the book, http://book.cakephp.org/view/1152/Core-Validation-Rules#isUnique-1166

If you are calling it using AJAX or similar where the model isn't being called as part of a `save()` you can always

```
$this->Model->set($this->data);
if($this->Model->validates($this->data){
  // Validation passed
}else{
  // Process validation errors, using
  $this->Model->invalidFields;
}
```